# Examples of 3d visual proofs

Tags: examples-counterexamples, 3d, big-list, visualization, proof-without-words

I am looking for examples of three dimensional constructible proofs. By this I mean [activities such as steps in proving $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03025326#page-1). In this construction the identity is proven by assembling 6  special pyramids that interlock to make a box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the best 3d proof. There is a bijection between the following two kinds of combinatorial objects:

- [Plane partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) fitting in a cube with side lengths $n$, and
- [Rhombus tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombille_tiling) fitting in a hexagon with side lengths $n$.

The proof is by [lookin'](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/rhombus-tilings-and-a-nice-bijection/):

[image]

Comment: I can get down with lookin' at that. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

1. Some geometric proofs using series: http://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume7/Styer/Series3.html
2. Article **Geometric Progressions - A Geometric Approach** by Michael Strizhevsky, in [Nov.2001 edition](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal-november-2001) of *College Mathematics Journal*